# Order by one of two fields

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have a model that has two character fields, one or both of which may be populated. I'd like to called `QuerySet.order_by` something like:

```
qs.alias(name=lambda x: if x.field1 then x.field1 else x.field2).order_by('name')
```

That is, for each row, take the value that you're ordering by from `field1` if it's defined, and from `field2` if it's not. Is there any way to accomplish this with a Django queryset?

Comment: So you check if these are `NULL`?

Answer (score 1):

What you aim to do is basically a [**`Coalesce`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/database-functions/#coalesce):

```
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce

qs.alias(name=Coalesce('field1', 'field2')).order_by('name')
```

If it is about empty items, you will need a [*conditional expression* <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#conditional-expressions):

```
from django.db.models import Case, F, Q, When

qs.alias(
    name=Case(
        When(Q(field1=None) | Q(field1=''), then=F('field2')),
        default=F('field1'),
    )
).order_by('name')
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is doable by using the `.annotate()` method in conjunction with a few built-in tools from **django.db.models**, see below:

```py
from django.db.models import Case, When, Value, CharField
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce

qs = YourModel.objects.annotate(
    name=Case(
        When(field1__isnull=False, then='field1'),
        When(field1__isnull=True, then='field2'),
        output_field=CharField()
    )
).order_by('name')
```

If this is the full extent of your query, then a more concise but slightly more opaque way of doing it is:

```py
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce

qs = YourModel.objects.annotate(
    name=Coalesce('field1', 'field2')
).order_by('name')
```

**Coalesce** works as follows (from [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/database-functions/)):

*`Coalesce` accepts a list of at least two field names or expressions and returns the first non-null value (note that an empty string is not considered a null value). Each argument must be of a similar type, so mixing text and numbers will result in a database error.*

I'm a huge fan of **.annotate()**, reckon it's one of the best ways to get the most out of Django's ORM without going into raw SQL!

Comment: `.ailas(..)` is in variant of `.annotate`, with as difference that it does not appear in the `SELECT` clause, so in case the `.name` is not necessary as attribute, `.annotate` can be substituted by `.alias`.